# C# cant find a unity auto generated class

Tags: c#, visual-studio, class, unity-game-engine, namespaces

Okay so I'm learning to use the new InputActions and I've created a C# scripts using

https://prnt.sc/oyaj5l

And this is what I got:

```
// GENERATED AUTOMATICALLY FROM 'Assets/PlayerControls.inputactions'

using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine.InputSystem;
using UnityEngine.InputSystem.Utilities;

public class PlayerControls : IInputActionCollection
{
    private InputActionAsset asset;
    public PlayerControls()
    {
        ///
    }
}
```

But when I try to create an PlayerControls object, I get an error saying

> The type or namespace name 'PlayerControls' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

This is the class where I try to reference it:

```
using System;
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityStandardAssets.CrossPlatformInput;
using UnityStandardAssets.Utility;
using Random = UnityEngine.Random;
using UnityEngine.InputSystem;

namespace UnityStandardAssets.Characters.FirstPerson
{
    public class FirstPersonController : MonoBehaviour
    {
        private PlayerControls controls; // ERROR HERE
    }
}
```

Comment: Just checked, I can't reference any of the scripts I made in the global namespace from the FirstPersonController class

Answer (score 1):

Wrap the `PlayerControls` class in a namespace, then add a `using` statement in your class that points to the namespace where your `PlayerControls` class lives.

Comment: Yeah but the PlayerControls class is in the global namespace? See the first code

Comment: It doesn't look like any namespace is declared around the PlayerControls class.

Comment: Still doesn't work.. I can access unity default classes but not my own

Comment: Can you please update your question to show new code?

Comment: @TrevorBrooks if you don't explicitly wrap a class in a custom namespace it is added to a ["default" or "global" namespace](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/namespace) which automatically is present in every file  .. so this shouldn't be the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it!
It looks like Unity has a compile order. I referenced this: http://answers.unity.com/answers/1274460/view.html and managed to solve it after seeing that "Standard Assets" has priority over other assets